# How to pass data to select2 version > 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am trying to use `select2` for the first time.

I would like to have my data from a static array. Can you please help me?

**Here is my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var names = [{"id":"1","name":"Adair,James"}
             , {"id":"2","name":"Anderson,Peter"}
             , {"id":"3","name":"Armstrong,Ryan"}];

    $("#e10_2").select2({
        processResults: function(){
          return {
            results: $.map(names, function(obj) {
              return { id: obj.id, text: obj.name };
            })
          };
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `data` option to pass an array to the `select2` as :

```
$("#e10_2").select2({ data: names });
```

If you don't have `text` attribute adapt your array check the part of documentation made for this purpose **[`The id and text properties are strictly enforced`](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id)**, e.g :

```
$(function () {
    var names = [{"id":"1","name":"Adair James"}
                 , {"id":"2","name":"Anderson Peter"}
                 , {"id":"3","name":"Armstrong Ryan"}];

    var data = $.map(names, function (obj) {
      obj.id = obj.id;
      obj.text = obj.name;

      return obj;
    });

    $("select").select2({width: '100%',data: data});
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
  var names = [{"id":"1","name":"Adair James"}
               , {"id":"2","name":"Anderson Peter"}
               , {"id":"3","name":"Armstrong Ryan"}];

  var data = $.map(names, function (obj) {
    obj.id = obj.id;
    obj.text = obj.name;

    return obj;
  });

  $("select").select2({width: '100%',data: data});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select></select>
```

Comment: I don't have text property in my data, so it will not show any data

Comment: Ok @Vishal i see.. you should just adapt your array, check my update.